# Micropython paho module missing?

Tags: python, esp8266, paho, nodemcu, micropython

I'm trying to build a basic MQTT publisher using a nodemcu v3 and a dht11 to send temperature data. I'm using ESPlorer and when I try to upload my code it tells me that the `paho` module does not exist. My code is as follows:

```
import time
import network
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

sta_if = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
ap_if = network.WLAN(network.AP_IF)
sta_if.connect('<MySSID>', '<MyPW>')

mqtt = mqtt.Client()
mqtt.connect("randomIPaddress")

pin = machine.Pin(4)
temp_instance = dht11.DHT11(pin)
result = temp_instance.read()

print("Temperature is: %d C" % result.temperature)
print("Humidity is: %d %%" % result.humidity)
message = result.temperature 
mqtt.publish("base/dht11/temp", message)  
mqtt.loop_forever()
```

I'm still very confused by how MQTT publishing works, and I can't seem to find any sources that agree with each other on this. Everywhere I look has a different solution for my problem.

Does anyone have an idea why ESPLorer keeps telling me that the `paho` module doesn't exist? I've already tried installing the module as shown in the documentation but that got me nowhere.

Edit:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paho-mqtt/1.1
These where the instructions I followed to install paho.

Comment: Can you please post the instructions you followed to install `paho`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your code looks like Python so I added the corresponding tag. To get more detailed answers, consider adding the exact error you are getting to the question. Also, as @killthrush suggested, can you add how you installed paho?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paho-mqtt/1.1

Those are the instructions I followed to install paho. Where they the wrong ones?

Answer (score 5):

The `paho` MQTT client has been written for regular Python. It is unlikely that it would run under MicroPython.

MicroPython includes its own MQTT client called `umqtt`.  There are two versions, [umqtt.simple](https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/tree/master/umqtt.simple) and [umqtt.robust](https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/tree/master/umqtt.robust).

You can see an example that uses it [here](https://home-assistant.io/blog/2016/08/31/esp8266-and-micropython-part2/).

Comment: Ahhhhh I see! Thanks so much for the help!